# How to render material channels (Albedo, Roughness, Metallic, Normal, etc)?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, scene

How can I render specific material channels in a scene in Blender?
So far, the methods that I have found on the Internet are very long and complex and are not suitable for scenes where there is a lot of materials. In Marmoset Toolbag, such renderings are made very easily; all I need to do is select the channels that I want to render. Are there equally easy ways to do this in Blender?

I am attaching a screenshot from ArtStation as an example. (Author - Vadym Samchuk)

[image]

Comment: Inside properties panel> view layer >passes. Make sure tu set the render engine to cycles to have all the option

Comment: @Emir Would you like to add this as an answer?

Comment: @Leander I'm pretty sure that this is a duplicate, but not sure yet

Comment: @Emir Unfortunately no. Passes give a different result. There is no Roughness, Metallic, Normal.